# What's the easiest way to find an unused local port?

Tags: shell, networking, shell-script, netstat

What's the easiest way to find an unused local port?

Currently I'm using something similar to this:

```
port=$RANDOM
quit=0

while [ "$quit" -ne 1 ]; do
  netstat -a | grep $port >> /dev/null
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    quit=1
  else
    port=`expr $port + 1`
  fi
done
```

It feels awfully roundabout, so I'm wondering if there's a more simple path such as a builtin that I've missed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's inherently racy (and inefficient - and least add `-n` to netstat and a more selective grep). The way to do it is to try and open a port in whatever mode you need, and try another one if it's not available.

Comment: @Mat I'm trying to automatically find an open port to use with `ssh -D` as a SOCKS server.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308144/how-to-get-the-first-available-tcp-port-to-listen-to || POSIX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913501/how-to-let-kernel-choose-a-port-number-in-the-range-1024-5000-in-tcp-socket-pr

Comment: Not a duplicate, since it was asked after, and in a different SE site, but I answered there with a portable sh(1) script that would nicely answer this one too.  To not repeat the answer, I'm linking from here: <https://superuser.com/a/1746110/658727>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If your application supports it, you can try passing port 0 to the application. If your application passes this to the kernel, the port will be dynamically allocated at request time, and is guaranteed not to be in use (allocation will fail if all ports are already in use).

Otherwise, you can do this manually. The script in your answer has a race condition, the only way to avoid it is to atomically check if it is open by trying to open it. If the port is in use, the program should quit with a failure to open the port.

For example, say you're trying to listen with GNU netcat.

```
#!/bin/bash
read lower_port upper_port < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
while :; do
    for (( port = lower_port ; port <= upper_port ; port++ )); do
        nc -l -p "$port" 2>/dev/null && break 2
    done
done
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Where do you see a race condition here?

Comment: This port tries to use the first port available. When you have two concurrent processes, then the port which just got checked might be reused. Re-reading your answer, it seems that you suggest to retry binding on an available port until all ports are exhausted. Assuming that the program in question can distinguish between "port in use" and other errors, it should be fine (though randomization would still make it better for unpredictability).

Comment: @Lekensteyn Successful port binding results in the kernel returning EADDRINUSE if you try and use it again, it's not possible that "the port which just got checked might be reused".

Comment: Yes, I wrongly assumed that you would exit the loop and use `$port` in the actual program as in `while ...; done; program --port $port`.

Comment: From the man page:  -p source_port
 Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

Comment: @monksy Your version of nc is not GNU netcat, then. You're probably using OpenBSD netcat, which has different options.

Comment: This is not really all that useful if you then want to know what port number was picked and do something with it; you'll inevitably run into a race condition there.

Comment: @dramzy You don't have to run into a race condition. Launch the program, get notified (by something like `sd_notify`) about successful startup, then record the last port entered (or pass it through dbus, or whatever IPC you like).

Comment: @Chris In my case, I have no control over the process that uses the port since I am running a Postgres instance. The process will exit with an error code if the port is in use or it will run indefinitely otherwise. The solution I can think of involves a race condition with a wait and a retry.

Answer (score 91):

My solution is to bind to port 0, which asks the kernel to allocate a port from it's ip_local_port_range. Then, close the socket and use that port number in your configuration.

This works because the kernel doesn't seem to reuse port numbers until it absolutely has to. Subsequent binds to port 0 will allocate a different port number. Python code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
addr = s.getsockname()
print(addr[1])
s.close()
```

This gives just a number of a port, eg. `60123`.

Run this program 10 000 times (you should run these concurrently), and you'll get 10 000 different port numbers. Therefore, I think it's pretty safe to use the ports.

Comment: Here is a one-liner (valid with Python 2 and Python 3): `python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()'`

Comment: I ran the mentioned experiment, and not all results were unique. My histogram was: `{ 1: 7006, 2: 1249, 3: 151, 4: 8, 5: 1, 6: 1}`

Comment: Is there an easy way to add in a check that the port is not blocked by a firewall, or rather only searches open ports?

Comment: I ran the script 10,000 times and got similar results to @bukzor: 1282 ports used twice, 153 used 3 times, 10 used 4 times and 1 used 5 times.

Comment: @dshepherd I believe you'll get different ports if you do not close the previous one (and close them all at once at last).

Comment: One liner for Ruby 2.3.1: `ruby -e 'puts Addrinfo.tcp("", 0).bind { |s| s.local_address.ip_port }'`

Comment: Here's an example of how to get the value from the python script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171914/289099

Comment: @FranklinYu - that didn't work for me (ruby 2.1.6p336).  This did:   `ruby -e 'require "socket"; puts Addrinfo.tcp("", 0).bind {|s| s.local_address.ip_port }'`

Comment: Thank you for giving me the name, `ip_local_port_range`.

Comment: you'll want to do `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` in order to be actually able to use the port immediately afterwards

Comment: It's 2024. Is there no standard command for this? Like `get-open-port`?

Answer (score 36):

#### One-liner

I've put together a nice one-liner that quickly serves the purpose, allowing to grab an arbitrary number of ports in an arbitrary range (here it's divided in 4 lines for readability):

```bash
comm -23 \
<(seq "$FROM" "$TO" | sort) \
<(ss -Htan | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2 | sort -u) \
| shuf | head -n "$HOWMANY"
```

#### Line by line

`comm` is a utility that compares lines in two files that must appear sorted alphabetically. It outputs three columns: lines that appear only in the first file, lines that only appear in the second one and common lines. By specifying `-23` we suppress the latter columns and only keep the first one. We can use this to obtain the difference of two sets, expressed as a sequence of text lines. I learned about `comm` [here](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2013/03/set-difference-of-two-lists-using-bash-shell/).

The first file is the range of ports that we can select from. `seq` produces a sorted sequence of numbers from `$FROM` to `$TO`. The result is sorted alphabetically (instead of numerically, in order to comply with `comm`s requirement) and piped to `comm` as the first file using [process substitution](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh).

The second file is the sorted list of ports, that we obtain by calling the `ss` command (with `-t` meaning TCP ports, `-a` meaning all - established and listening - and `-n` numeric - don't try to resolve, say, `22` to `ssh`). We then pick only the fourth column with `awk`, which contains the local address and port. We use `cut` to split address and port with the `:` delimiter and keep only the latter (`-f2`). We then comply with `comm`'s requirement by `sort`ing without duplicates `-u`.

Now we have a sorted list of open ports, that we can `shuf`fle to then grab the first `"$HOWMANY"` ones with `head -n`.

#### Example

Grab the three random open ports in the private range (49152-65535)

```
comm -23 <(seq 49152 65535 | sort) <(ss -Htan | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d':' -f2 | sort -u) | shuf | head -n 3
```

could return for example

```
54930
57937
51399
```

#### Notes

- switch `-t` with `-u` in `ss` to get free UDP ports instead.
- replace `shuf` with `sort -n` if you prefer to get available ports numerically sorted instead of at random

Comment: I like this one +1. You can also use `-H` to suppress `ss` headers so you can avoid `grep`ping to get only numbers.

Comment: I also think that the `sort` in the first process substitution is not needed.

Comment: @whoan Thanks for the tip regarding the header, I made it part of the answer. `sort`ing in the first process substitution makes sure that the output of `seq` is sorted _alphabetically_ instead of _numerically_ (which is `seq`s default) to comply with `comm`s requirement for the input to be `sort`ed like that. I've modified the answer to be more explicit about it. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think `seq` is POSIX.

Answer (score 17):

Apparently [TCP connections can be used as file descriptors](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html) on linux from with in bash/zsh. The following function uses that technique and should be faster than invoking netcat/telnet.

```
function EPHEMERAL_PORT() {
    LOW_BOUND=49152
    RANGE=16384
    while true; do
        CANDIDATE=$[$LOW_BOUND + ($RANDOM % $RANGE)]
        (echo "" >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/${CANDIDATE}) >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo $CANDIDATE
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

Usage instructions: Bind the output to a variable and use in scripts. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@ubuntu:~> EPHEMERAL_PORT
59453
root@ubuntu:~> PORT=$(EPHEMERAL_PORT)
```

Comment: Works with`ksh93` also.

Comment: If you change UPORT to 32768, you can still get EG 35835. RANDOM returns a number in [0,32767]. Modding this by a number greater than the max has no effect. You want something like `$[$LPORT + ($RANDOM % ($UPORT-$LPORT))]`.

Comment: Otherwise pretty cool though!

Comment: This sends `\n` to any listening port though :) I'd suggest adding `-n`. This will still try to open a connection but not send anything but immediately disconnect.

Answer (score 15):

```
#!/bin/bash
read LOWERPORT UPPERPORT < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
while :
do
        PORT="`shuf -i $LOWERPORT-$UPPERPORT -n 1`"
        ss -lpna | grep -q ":$PORT " || break
done
echo $PORT
```

"ss -lpn" - will show only ports with established connectios. We should use

"ss -lpna" to consider  listening ports too

Credits to Chris Down

Answer (score 13):

Here's a cross-platform, efficient "oneliner" that slurps up all in-use ports and gives you the first available one from 3000 onwards:

```
netstat -aln | awk '
  $6 == "LISTEN" {
    if ($4 ~ "[.:][0-9]+$") {
      split($4, a, /[:.]/);
      port = a[length(a)];
      p[port] = 1
    }
  }
  END {
    for (i = 3000; i < 65000 && p[i]; i++){};
    if (i == 65000) {exit 1};
    print i
  }
'
```

You can simply join all lines to have it on one line. If you want to get the first available from a different port number, change the assignment to `i` in the `for` loop.

It works on both Mac and Linux, which is why the `[:.]` regex is needed.

Comment: Why `-a` and not `-t` to just look at TCP(6) sockets?

Comment: And while we are at it, parsing the output of `ss -Htnl` might be better (and faster! - not that *I* care about that :P).

Comment: @stefanct BSD netstat doesn't have `-t`, at least the one that Apple ships with, and `ss` is also not present on macOS. `netstat -aln` even works on Solaris.

Comment: This should be higher up. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This is the version I use:

```
while
  port=$(shuf -n 1 -i 49152-65535)
  netstat -atun | grep -q "$port"
do
  continue
done

echo "$port"
```

The command `shuf -n 1 -i 49152-65535` gives you a "random" port in the dynamic range. If it is used already, another port in that range is tried.

The command `netstat -atun` lists all (-a) TCP (-t) and UDP (-u) ports without wasting time to determine hostnames (-n).

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, you could do something like:

```
ss -tln | 
  awk 'NR > 1{gsub(/.*:/,"",$4); print $4}' |
  sort -un |
  awk -v n=1080 '$0 < n {next}; $0 == n {n++; next}; {exit}; END {print n}'
```

To find the first free port above 1080. Note that `ssh -D` would bind on the loopback interface, so in theory you could reuse port 1080 if a socket has it bound on another address. Another way would be to actually try and bind it:

```
perl -MSocket -le 'socket S, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname("tcp");
  $port = 1080;
  ++$port until bind S, sockaddr_in($port,inet_aton("127.1"));
  print $port'
```

Comment: This does, however, involve a race condition between attempting to open the port and actually using it.

Comment: @ChrisDown, Indeed, but with `ssh -D`, I can't see any better option. The `-O forward` option of `ssh` doesn't return an error when the forward fail.

Answer (score 4):

If you have python lying around, I'd do this:

```
port="$(python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1])')";
echo "Unused Port: $port"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another run at this old hobby horse:

```
function random_free_tcp_port {
  local ports="${1:-1}" interim="${2:-2048}" spacing=32
  local free_ports=( )
  local taken_ports=( $( netstat -aln | egrep ^tcp | fgrep LISTEN |
                         awk '{print $4}' | egrep -o '[0-9]+$' |
                         sort -n | uniq ) )
  interim=$(( interim + (RANDOM % spacing) ))

  for taken in "${taken_ports[@]}" 65535
  do
    while [[ $interim -lt $taken && ${#free_ports[@]} -lt $ports ]]
    do
      free_ports+=( $interim )
      interim=$(( interim + spacing + (RANDOM % spacing) ))
    done
    interim=$(( interim > taken + spacing
                ? interim
                : taken + spacing + (RANDOM % spacing) ))
  done

  [[ ${#free_ports[@]} -ge $ports ]] || return 2

  printf '%d\n' "${free_ports[@]}"
}
```

This code makes purely portable use of `netstat`, `egrep`, `awk`, &al. Note that only one call is issued to external commands, to get a list of ports in use at the beginning. One can request one or more free ports:

```
:;  random_free_tcp_port
2070
:;  random_free_tcp_port 2
2073
2114
```

and start at an arbitrary port:

```
:;  random_free_tcp_port 2 10240
10245
10293
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one, albeit late to the party.  This one-liner even works with `busybox`:

```
for p in $(seq 3000 4000); do ss -tlnH | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -sf4 | grep -q "${p}$" || echo "${p}"; done | head -n 1
```

Change `seq 3000 4000` for `shuf -i 3000-4000` to get a random port.

Increase the number after `head -n` to return more than one free port.

This does require `ss` to be installed.  If it's not available, it's trivial to change `ss -tlnH` to `netstat -tln | tail -n +3` to use busybox's netstat instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a function I have in my .bashrc, which dynamically creates SSH tunnels and tries to use any port in a range:

```
   lps=( 7002 7003 7004 7005 7006 7007 7008 7009 7010 7011 )
   lp=null

   # find a free listening port
   for port in ${lps[@]}; do
      lsof -i -n -P |grep LISTEN |grep -q ":${port}"
      [ $? -eq 1 ] && { lp=$port; break; }
   done
   [ "$lp" = "null" ] && { echo "no free local ports available"; return 2; }
   return $port
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

```
while port=$(shuf -n1 -i $(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range | tr '\011' '-'))
netstat -atun | grep -q ":$port\s" ; do
    continue
done
echo $port
```

My combination from other answers above. Get it:

With shuf -n1 we take one random number from the range (-i) in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range. shuf need the syntax with dash, so we use tr to change the tab in a dash.

Next wie use netstat to show us all (-a) tcp and udp (-u -t) connections in numbers(-n), if we find our random port $port in this (start with a : and end with w whitespace (\s) then we need a other Port and so continue. Else (grep -q has a returncode > 0 we left the while loop and $port is set.

Answer (score 0):

My take on it... the function tries to find `n` consecutive free ports:

```
#!/bin/bash

RANDOM=$$

# Based on 
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55918/41065
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248319/41065
find_n_ports () {
    local n=$1
    RANDOM=$$
    read lower_port upper_port < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
    local tries=10
    while [ $((tries--)) -gt 0 ]; do
        # Sleep for 100 to 499 ms
        sleep "0.$((100+$RANDOM%399))"
        local start="`shuf -i $lower_port-$(($upper_port-$n-1)) -n 1`"
        local end=$(($start+$n-1))
        # create ss filter for $n consecutive ports starting with $start
        local filter=""
        local ports=$(seq $start $end)
        for p in $ports ; do
            filter="$filter or sport = $p"
        done
        # if none of the ports is in use return them
        if [ "$(ss -tHn "${filter# or}" | wc -l)" = "0" ] ; then
            echo "$ports"
            return 0
        fi
    done
    echo "Could not find $n consecutive ports">&2
    return 1
}

ports=$(find_n_ports 3)
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer for macOS, based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55918/56148) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423052/56148) answer:

```bsh
lower_port=`sysctl -n net.inet.ip.portrange.first`
upper_port=`sysctl -n net.inet.ip.portrange.last`

comm -23 \
<(seq "$lower_port" "$upper_port" | sort) \
<(sudo lsof -iTCP -n -P -sTCP:LISTEN -t | sort -u) \
| gshuf | head -n 1
```

You can change the `1` in `head -n 1` to another number (or a script argument variable) if you want multiple ports.

`shuf` is available as `gshuf` via the `coreutils` Homebrew package.

The port range code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924337/173497) on this Stack Overflow question:

- [How to let kernel choose a port number in the range (1024,5000) in TCP socket programming - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913501/how-to-let-kernel-choose-a-port-number-in-the-range-1024-5000-in-tcp-socket-pr)

Answer (score 0):

This script works for me on macOS

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -u                    # exit on undefined variable
bash -c 'set -o pipefail' # return code of first cmd to fail in a pipeline

# Print random open port. Inspired by
# https://superuser.com/a/1041677/537059

CHECK="do while"

while [[ ! -z $CHECK ]]; do
  PORT=$(((RANDOM % 60000) + 1025))
  # Match end of word boundary to avoid false positives,
  # e.g. 2000 matching 20000
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074458/639133
  CHECK=$(netstat -an -ptcp | grep LISTEN | grep -r "${PORT}\b")
done

echo ${PORT}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked w00t's answer, but I didn't want to have the same free port chosen upon each invocation. Adding an incremental update, this will select a free port at random between 3,000 to 13,000 (but if all of those are taken, it will incrementally search from that randomly selected port):

```
netstat -aln | awk '
  $6 == "LISTEN" {
    if ($4 ~ "[.:][0-9]+$") {
      split($4, a, /[:.]/);
      port = a[length(a)];
      p[port] = 1
    }
  }
  END {
    srand();
    start = int(3000 + rand()*10000);
    for (i = start; i < 65000 && p[i]; i++){};
    if (i == 65000) {exit 1};
    print i
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet one more answer. It is very similar to several of the provided ones, but some of these don't actually work for me. Some don't tell me which free port I could use. Some give me a port which is not really free. And others use shuffle which I don't need.

```bsh
read first last < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
# or define your own range, like:
# first=9000; last=10000

for port in $(seq $first $last); do
  ss -atun | grep -q ":$port " || break
done

echo $port
```

Or as a long one-liner:

```bsh
read first last < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range; for port in $(seq $first $last); do ss -atun | grep -q ":$port " || break; done; echo $port
```

Answer (score 0):

My take, similar to multiple ideas here. Randomly picks form a range and checks with `nc`

```
# Tries to find a free port randomly from a given range
random_free_port() {
  local max_attempts=5
  local low_range=8432
  local range=200
  for i in $(seq "${max_attempts}"); do
    # Pick a random port between 8432-8632
    local port="$(($low_range + $RANDOM % $range))"
    # Check if the port is not open
    if ! nc -z -w 0 localhost 8433; then
      echo "Found free port $port" 1>&2
      echo "${port}"
      return
    fi
  done
  echo "Unable to find a free port after 5 attempts" 1>&2
  return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in name;
  char *addr;

  if(argc<2) {
     addr="0.0.0.0";
  } else {
     addr=argv[1];
  }
  /* Create the socket. */
  sock = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    {
      perror ("socket");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Give the socket a name. */
  name.sin_family = AF_INET;
  name.sin_port = htons (0);
  name.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);
  if (bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof (name)) < 0)
    {
      perror ("bind");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  int len = sizeof(name);
  int sn = getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&name, &len);
  printf("Port is %d\n",ntohs(name.sin_port));
  return sock;
}
```

Compile:
gcc getport.c -o getport

Usage: ./getport [address]

```
Ouput:
./getport
Port is 31725
./getport 127.0.0.1
Port is 32064
./getport 1.2.3.4
bind: Cannot assign requested address
```