# Does there exist an epheral port allocation service?

Tags: services, port

Following up on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-an-unused-local-port/55918), it would seem that a server that allocates ports within a namespace would be an obvious and useful capability. One use case for such a service/server would be a collection of co-referential microservers that use each other for tasks. I'd see the usage as:

- Every microserver that wants to make a port available contacts the port server to register itself by the service name that it provides.
- Every microserver that wants to use another service asks the port server for the port that corresponds to the service name it wants.

I haven't been able to find anything that does this. Does such a service exist?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)?

Comment: Sounds like [`portmap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap) to me.

Comment: @they I could go for that.

Comment: Micro services are often containerised meaning there is rarely a need to allocate ports within a namespace since each micro service runs in its own container and thus its own namespace.

Comment: As an example multiple co-related docker containers can reference each other by host name. Instead of using ephemeral ports each one uses a fixed port on its own (docker) ip address. Containers on the same docker network can resolve the ip of any other container by container name through DNS.